# Divide tuple into multiple sub-tuples - Python

Tags: python, tuples

Not sure how to express this spefically in the title. But let's say I have this tuple:

```
[['a',2,3],['a',4,5],['b',10,20],['b',30,40],['a',5,6]]
```

How do I divide this tuple into two tuples:

```
a = [[2,3],[4,5],[5,6]]
b = [[10,20],[30,40]]
```

Comment: These are known as lists btw

Comment: What have you tried and what exactly is the problem with it? You might be better off with a dictionary with keys `'a'` and `'b'`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `'a'` and `'b'` are meaningful constants that deserve to be hard-coded, a simple solution:

```
arr = [['a',2,3],['a',4,5],['b',10,20],['b',30,40],['a',5,6]]
a = [l[1:] for l in arr if l[0] == 'a']
b = [l[1:] for l in arr if l[0] == 'b']
```

If a more generic code is needed:

```
from collections import defaultdict

arr = [['a',2,3],['a',4,5],['b',10,20],['b',30,40],['a',5,6]]

d = defaultdict(list)
for l in arr:
    d[l[0]].append(l[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using list comprehension:

```
>>> l = [['a',2,3],['a',4,5],['b',10,20],['b',30,40],['a',5,6]]

>>> a = [x[1:] for x in l if x[0] == "a"]

>>> a
[[2, 3], [4, 5], [5, 6]]

>>> b = [x[1:] for x in l if x[0] == "b"]

>>> b
[[10, 20], [30, 40]]

>>>
```

You need to iterate over the elements (sublists) in the main list. For each sublist, we check if the first item. If the first item is `a` or `b`, we then slice the sub list and only take the integer parts.

Answer (score 0):

As jonrsharpe suggests, it's probably more useful to store those lists in a dictionary. It's easy to divide the sublists in the way you want using a dictionary to accumulate the sublists into lists as the values with the strings as the keys. And of course you can bind the resulting lists to separate names if you really want to.

```
seq = [['a', 2, 3], ['a', 4, 5], ['b', 10, 20], ['b', 30, 40], ['a', 5, 6]]
d = {}
for k, *u in seq:
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(u)

print(d)
a = d['a']
b = d['b']
print(a)
print(b)
```

**output**

```
{'a': [[2, 3], [4, 5], [5, 6]], 'b': [[10, 20], [30, 40]]}
[[2, 3], [4, 5], [5, 6]]
[[10, 20], [30, 40]]
```

`for k, *u in seq:` binds the string in each sublist to `k`, storing the remainder of the sublist as `u`. We then append the `u` sublist to the appropriate list in the dictionary `d`.

Comment: Thanks! Storing the lists into a dictionary is probably the most elegant solution for what I'm working at.